# How to get JS value in UIWebView in Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

I've added to my HTML these lines:

```
"</script>$(document).ready(func a() {
    $('img').click(function(){
        return $(this).attr('src');
    });
});</script>"
```

and if I set instead of `return` - `alert`, then I get what I need.

Later I've tried this on my tap recognizer function:

```
var a = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("a()")
print(a)
```

but it prints me an empty string. What I do wrong? Can anyone help me to fix that?

Comment: you're not really returning a string are you? try func a() { return "hello" }

Comment: @daven11 the same thing, I get an empty string ""

Comment: there's some reading here https://www.jayway.com/2010/06/28/uiwebview-and-javascript-woes/ try an alert("hello"); followed by a return "hello"; maybe. That will make sure the function is executed

Comment: Should that be "function a()" not "func a()"?

Comment: @daven11 yes, it calls, but did not print anything, just empty string

Comment: @daven11 alert gives me a source string, but I do not get anything in print(a)

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late but AFAIK you should call "a();". You might be missing the semicolon